# Forgetting self qualifier: how to catch this mistake?

Tags: python, debugging, self

I understand why Python requires explicit `self` qualifier when referring to instance attributes.

But I often forget it, since I didn't need it in C++.

The bug I introduce this way is sometimes extremely hard to catch; e.g., suppose I write

```
if x is not None:
    f()
```

instead of

```
if self.x is not None:
    f()
```

Suppose attribute `x` is usually `None`, so `f()` is rarely called. And suppose `f()` only creates a subtle side effect (e.g., a change in a numeric value, or clearing the cache, etc.). Unless I have insane amount of unit tests, this mistake is likely to remain unnoticed for a long time.

I am wondering if anyone knows coding techniques or IDE features that could help me catch or avoid this type of bug.

Comment: Do not name your variables as `x`, etc.

Comment: @Hamish, give him a break, it's just sample code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't name your instance attributes the same things as your globals/locals.

If there isn't a global/local of the same name, you'll get a `global "foo" is not defined` error when you try to access `self.foo` but forget the `self.`.

As a corollary: give your variables descriptive names. Don't name everything `x` - not only does this make it far less likely you'll have variables with the same name as attributes, it also makes your code easier to read.

Comment: Ahh, perfect. I'm already doing everything as you said, I just didn't realize that global variables won't be defined just by referring to them! :) I should add that I just tried the assignment 

x = 'something'

and it also was caught at compile-time:

AttributeError: 'Parser' object has no attribute 'x'

So everything is fine.